# ASP.Net...Quantity Textbox?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, textbox

Basically I wanted the user to type in a quantity number in a textbox, then the number will be shown in a label in the Bill Page

This code is placed in my Book Online Page

```
String PersonNumber = TxtNumber.Text;
        int PersonQNumber = int.Parse(PersonNumber);
        Session.Add("sPersonNumber", PersonQNumber.ToString());
```

for some reason visual basic 2012 asp.net, gives me an error and highlights on 
int.Parse(PersonNumber);

...........................

and

```
String PersonQNum = (String)Session["sPersonNumber"];
        LblNumber.Text = PersonQNum;
```

this code is placed in my Bill Page

Comment: Is clear that you not enter a number, or the editor is empty... Why all that to make it int, then string, then session, then again add it to text ? Saves it as it is to session, then convert it to int. By the way, bad idea and bad design to save it on session to move that value around.

Comment: What is the specific error you get? Keep in mind that `int.Parse()` will throw an error if the input isn't actually a number.

Comment: Our teacher wants it to be this way, yet the propram is not accepting it. I converted the string into int...because its a textbox and the user is going to type in a number.. then I wanted it to get back to string so I use it for the other Bill page. Please help me if you have a better code. :(

Comment: the program highlights int PersonQNumber= int.Parse(PersonNumber);

Comment: String PersonNumber = TxtNumber.Text;
            int PersonQNumber= int.Parse(PersonNumber);
            Session.Add("sPersonNumber", PersonQNumber.ToString());
the program highlights this line

int PersonQNumber= int.Parse(PersonNumber);

as an error

Answer (score 0):

You can try using TryParse to convert the TxtNumber.Text value:

```
int PersonQNumber = 0;
int.TryParse(TxtNumber.Text, PersonQNumber)
```

Comment: What happened? Did it not return a value or did something throw an error? Also, try using the debugger to check the value of the textbox. (You can do this by selecting TxtNumber.Text, right click, then 'Add to watch'.  A window should show you what the value is.)